# PHP & Mongo: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, mongodb

Trollslayers.
I have got problem with some ugly trolls hiding in php configuration.
When I try to use Mongodb, something goes wrong.

System: Linux Mint LMDE 2014 Trolled Edition.

Installed:

- PHP 5.3.x BruteForced Denied to Update
- PHP with dev,mysql,curl,fpm,mcrypt, and other food for trolls from dark forest.
- Newest Nginx.

When I try to use php as bash command, I see message from hungry troll:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongodb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs => /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
```

If I want to call phpinfo(); I do not see any informations about installed mongo - ctrl+f("mongo") returns nothing. (during installation there was no any suspicious messages).

So, I can not to cook any soup without mongo spice.
Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your troll denied your chef permissions to create `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongodb.so' when your dragon slayer was assembling recipes by for your chef to cook from.

The troll however, in trolling fashion, did allow your chef to update your php.ini soup - pretending the chef got all the ingredients it needed.

When your chef now tries to load all the ingredients that your dragon slayer requires, it cannot find the mongodb.so spice as it does not exist.

On second thought. I think your chef made a typo. It is called `mongo.so`, not mongodb.so

If not, please attempt to slay the dragon with `sudo pecl install mongo`